# How to prevent a person B to kick of person A remote desktop connection, on Windows?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-access, remote-control, remote-connection

Person A and Person B use the same non-admin Windows user account to start remote desktop connection.
Person A starts remote desktop connection and works on a document. When person B then starts another remote desktop session, it kicks-off (terminates) previous remote desktop connection established by person A, even without any warning.
How can I prevent that?
(I wish to set that another person cannot terminate previously established remote desktop connection without explicit permission by person who started connection first...)

Comment: Depending on the host you're connecting to, you should be able to run 2 remote sessions. 1 in the admin console, and another as a domain user. Why not just give the users domain accounts remote access?

Comment: Not going into details, but those two users must use the same Windows non-admin user account. Running two or more concurrent sessions for the same Windows user account is also not an option. The question is how to prevent person B to terminate already established remote connection by person A.

Comment: What is the OS version?

Comment: Is this on Windows Server?

Comment: Yes, Windows Server 2016

Comment: Is the ability to ask for permission (via the same mechanism) a strict requirement, or would it suffice if it's only possible to connect when there is no active session?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question but just today I was confronted with the same problem. I stumbled on this thread while looking for an answer. Not having found a solution anywhere I had to roll up my sleeves, build a test environment and do some testing. Here is the solution:

- Open gpedit and go to `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Connections`.
- Find the setting `Limit number of connections`. Set it to "Enabled" and set the value for `RD Maximum Connection allowed` to 1. Reboot or run gpupdate.

After this is applied, when a second user tries to login to a machine with another user logged in, this is what they will see:

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Tried in Windows Server 2019, didn't work when someone else connects with the same username. It still kicks the first session out.

Answer (score 2):

Remote Desktop/Terminal Services has two settings for multiple sessions:
You can either allow multiple sessions per user
(in which case if you log in twice, you'll get two sessions),
or force a single session per user
(in which case you can only log in once and subsequent sessions will be redirected to the original session).

To change this setting:

- Start 'regedit.exe'
- Navigate to the following registry key:
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer`
- If the value `fSingleSessionPerUser` doesn't exist, create it as DWORD
- The `fSingleSessionPerUser` values are as follows:

  - `0x0` : Allow multiple sessions per user
  - `0x1` : Force each user to a single session
- Enter the new value and click OK.

Comment: Hi, I wish to allow only single session per user. But, the problem is that if person A first starts remote session for the Windows user X, and then person B starts new session for the Windows user X, new session terminates the previous one. I need it opposite way - that user B cannot start new session while user A is connected. I hope this clarifies the essence of my question.

Comment: Try in `gpedit` to go to "Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Connections\" and enable "Restrict Remote Desktop Services users to a single Remote Desktop Services session" and reboot. The documentation isn't very clear on what is the difference between Not configured and Enabled. If this does not make a difference, then I don't know of any other solution.