# Prevent one client to access "in-use" RDP session by another client on the same user (win 10)

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

We have 1 windows 10 PC.

We have 2 clients using the same PC on the Same user.

We now facing the issue that one client "kick" the other client from the session while in use.

I want to be able to prevent access (take control and kick the connected client) to this specific-user while there is "input" - like mouse move by connected client, or at least to rise a prompt msg on the connected client session to allow / reject.

I saw that "input" does exist but only for timeout:
[Timeout on - no input]  https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWbdH.png

Can it be done ?

Can I runover some configurations using an external tool ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent a person B to kick of person A remote desktop connection, on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1481020/how-to-prevent-a-person-b-to-kick-of-person-a-remote-desktop-connection-on-wind)

Comment: I will try that. but than I will need to force disconnection after X time no input.

Comment: This is not solving my problem. The PC have more than 1 user on it, so many clients works on many users, but 1 users shall be limit to the specific session.

Comment: "You can use this setting to restrict the number of Remote Desktop Services sessions that can be active on a server. If this number is exceeded, addtional users who try to connect receive an error message telling them that the server is busy and to try again later. Restricting the number of sessions improves performance because fewer sessions are demanding system resources. By default, RD Session Host servers allow an unlimited number of Remote Desktop Services sessions, and Remote Desktop for Administration allows two Remote Desktop Services sessions."