# how do I prevent user B remote login when user A also remotely using the same account on windows 10 computer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-access, remote

I have a problem that bothers me for a while.

When there is a user A remotely login my windows computer(win 10),
user B will kick user A out if B remotely login with same account.

Can I prevent this condition and let A continues to normally use computer?

I've tried the method in the following website:[How to prevent a person B to kick of person A remote desktop connection, on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1481020/how-to-prevent-a-person-b-to-kick-of-person-a-remote-desktop-connection-on-wind)

But it didn't work...

Please hele me!

Comment: Different users should use different accounts. Then is just a matter of setting it up to allow concurrent sessions or not, period. If you insist in a bad practice then this https://superuser.com/a/1481167/653259 and not the most voted answer is what *may* work.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Sorry, the method didn't work, too...

Comment: Unsurprisingly. It was a best effort anyway, based on some assumptions. The point is there's no settings or provisions for such scenario because such scenario shouldn't happen, it's as simple as that.