# Windows 11 prevent connection via Remote Desktop Connection until existing session times out

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11

This question is a little contrary to standard assumptions with Remote Desktop.  Usually, the assumption is, user A can login from computer X and then log in from computer Y, causing X to disconnect and the session to continue on Y.

I'd like to prevent Y from opening that connection as long as the connection from X is still active.  I will use a 15 minute idle disconnect to make it available to Y.

I've tested and confirmed it's working in Windows Server Standard 2022 using these settings : [How to prevent a person B to kick of person A remote desktop connection, on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1481020/how-to-prevent-a-person-b-to-kick-of-person-a-remote-desktop-connection-on-wind)

Windows 11 does not seem to mind these settings (yes, I tried gpupdate and reboots) .  Does Windows 11 have a means of preventing subsequent connection attempts while a Remote Desktop Connection is active?

Comment: This setting is for Windows Server with Remote Desktop Session Host role service. It does not apply to a client version such as Windows 11.

Answer (score 1):

We currently can do this with VMware. By having users connect through the Horizon client.  It will prevent a second user form connecting until the first has disconnected.
But if you don't have VMware Horizon.  I do not believe there is a way.  This is the info I have found: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/remote-desktop-control-how-to-disable-the-second/bbd98012-4f2c-4386-b48a-d5ef161d7821

Cheers,

Comment: Good to know.  We don't use that right now but might have to.

Comment: Please note that the relevant information from the link MUST be included in the body of this answer in order for it to qualify as an answer per the rules of this site. The link should remain for attribution and further research, but the answer must all be here.